The negative value of the hopping integral in the tight-binding model Hamiltonian
In the book Physical Properties of Carbon Nanotubes by Riichiro Saito, Gene Dresselhaus, and Mildred S. Dresselhaus (Chapter 2, page 23), the tight-binding model Hamiltonian for atoms A and B in polyacetylene is given by
$$H_{AB}(r) = 2t \cos\left(\frac{ka}{2}\right)\tag{2.17}$$
with $$t = \langle \phi_A(r-R) | H | \phi_B(r-R \pm a/2) \rangle. \tag{2.18}$$
In the book, it is mentioned that $t$ has a negative value. I still don't understand why $t$ is negative. Is there any particular physical meaning behind this?

When $t$ has a negative value, the ground state is one that is spread out and smooth, whereas the high energy states have a lot of wiggling. Positive $t$ flips this around. The text is just trying to mention that this is the physically sensible situation.

Hopping integral is essentially a non-diagonal matrix element in a Hamiltonian. The principal constraint is that Hamiltonian should be Hermitian, but nothing prevents the non-diagonal elements from being negative or even complex numbers. They are usually real, since the orbitals are taken to be real functions, and the potential is real.
That $t$ in the energy dispersion in tight-binding model $\epsilon(k)=2t\cos(ka)$ is negative simply means that at $k=0$ the band has a minimum, rather than a maximum ($\cos(0)=1$). This facilitates using the effective-mass approximation:
$$\cos(ka)\approx 1-\frac{k^2a^2}{2}\Rightarrow \epsilon(k)=2t+\frac{2tk^2a^2}{2}=E_c+\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m^*},$$
which is very intuitive to anyone who studied Newtonian/classical mechanics.
Of course, in the case of graphene or metallic nanotubes the mass term is zero, but the goal of this answer is merely to show that negative $t$ is not particularly problematic, and often understood by convention. In some cases one would explicitly write: $\epsilon(k)=-\Delta\cos(ka)$ (with $\Delta=2|t|$ being positive bandwidth.)
